# LaTeX and Python works on Ubuntu but not on Windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, latex, miktex

I'm not particularly fluent with LaTeX, but I need to generate a bunch of SVG files given the raw input LaTeX code.  One way I found to do that was by using a Python script called "latex2svg", located here: https://github.com/tuxu/latex2svg.

I am able to do this successfully in Linux, but not in Windows, and I don't understand why.  In Ubuntu, if I run:

`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

to install LaTeX, and then create the following Python script (located in the same directory as latex2svg.py):

```
from latex2svg import latex2svg

myeq1 = r'e^{i\pi}+1=0'
myeq2 = r'\mathbb{Q}'
myeq3 = r'\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\ dx=1'

eqs = [myeq1, myeq2, myeq3]

for ii, eq in enumerate(eqs):
  myeq = r'\( ' + eq + r' \)'
  out = latex2svg(myeq)
  with open('out{}.svg'.format(ii), 'w') as f:
    f.write(out['svg'])
```

Everything works perfectly, and it generates the SVG files correctly (see them [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CoeF2rIGchIMSpSYUwprtaCH5oXrmRO4)):

However, on Windows 10, with MikTeX installed, if I run that exact same Python script, I get a warning `Warning: libgs not found`, but the script continues and outputs some half-broken SVGs (see them [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iVUhA-6XDhsqt-_LuuOTym7HUVqjTzWR)).  I tried to install libgs with pip, but I get [this horrible error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JdKMagG7Rmp3_Uak-J5rLvWvWA0-lyeV) and have no idea what to do about it.

What do I need to do to get this to work on Windows? Although I have it working on Ubuntu, I would like to understand the issue to get it working in Windows.

Comment: Uh, install `libgs`?

Comment: @tripleee, I attempted that, and don't understand why it failed.

Comment: Attempted what exactly? Failed how?

Comment: I tried to install libgs with pip, but I get this error and don't understand it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JdKMagG7Rmp3_Uak-J5rLvWvWA0-lyeV/view

Comment: Indeed it is not a Python component. Look for "GhostScript library for Windows" or some such; not unfortunately, I am not a Windows person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, even though it took me forever. The issue was that I didn't have the package listed here in the "latex2svg.py" file:

`\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`

If you remove that line, it renders OK. I'm not sure how to install it on Windows yet but that was the crux of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the python detour, you can directly compile to svg with

```
latex filename
dvisvgm filename.dvi
```

(wherein filename is the base name of your filename.tex file)